# Merge events temporally close to one another in numpy (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, svg

I would like to simplify a list of start and stop times.  When the time between the stop of one and the start of another, I'd like to combine (rows).  The following is a simplification of my data and what I would like as output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
start_time = [  1,  7, 20, 22, 27, 35]
stop_time  = [  5,  9, 22, 26, 30, 40]
events = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': start_time, 'stop_time': stop_time})
allowable_gap = 2.0

desired_start_time = [  1, 20, 35]
desired_stop_time  = [  9, 30, 40]
desired_events = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':desired_start_time, 'stop_time':desired_stop_time})
```

I have no requirement that I must use Pandas.  However, I need to at least use numpy.  The number of events is in the order of 1e6.

Thanks for any implementations or guidance.  I know that part of my problem is that I don't "get" Pandas.

My usage likely isn't relevant to the solution.  As background, I'm collecting a large number of events and then plotting them using matplotlib.pyplot.  As the output is complex, the best format I have found is .svg.  IE usually renders fine but takes and exceptionally long time to do so and I hope to reduce the number of lines that it has to draw.  I would love to view time series in a better way but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Are the events in order? I mean, we should combine the consecutive rows with distance <= gap? I'm OK? 
Another silly question: always start_time <= stop_time?

Comment: Yes, they are in order.  Yes, start_time always <= stop_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more efficient way to do that:

```
In [106]: (events.groupby((events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift() > allowable_gap).cumsum())
   .....:        .agg({'start_time':'min', 'stop_time':'max'})[['start_time','stop_time']])
Out[106]:
   start_time  stop_time
0           1          9
1          20         30
2          35         40
```

Timing against 60K rows DF:

```
In [129]: events = pd.concat([events] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [130]: events.shape
Out[130]: (60000, 2)

In [131]: %paste
def f():
    desired_start_time = []
    desired_stop_time  = []

    start = None
    end = None
    for index, row in events.iterrows():
        if start == None and end == None:
            start = row['start_time']
            end = row['stop_time']
        else:
            if end + allowable_gap >= row['start_time']:
                end = row['stop_time']
            else:
                desired_start_time.append(start)
                desired_stop_time.append(end)
                start = row['start_time']
                end = row['stop_time']
    desired_start_time.append(start)
    desired_stop_time.append(end)
## -- End pasted text --

In [132]: %timeit f()
1 loop, best of 3: 16.1 s per loop

In [133]: %%timeit
   .....: (events.groupby((events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift() > allowable_gap).cumsum())
   .....:        .agg({'start_time':'min', 'stop_time':'max'})[['start_time','stop_time']])
   .....:
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** "looping" solution is approx. 1000 times slower

Another timing for 6M rows DF:

```
In [153]: events = pd.concat([events] * 10**6, ignore_index=True)

In [154]: events.shape
Out[154]: (6000000, 2)

In [155]: %%timeit
   .....: (events.groupby((events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift() > allowable_gap).cumsum())
   .....:        .agg({'start_time':'min', 'stop_time':'max'})[['start_time','stop_time']])
   .....:
1 loop, best of 3: 1.49 s per loop
```

given and desired DFs:

```
In [98]: events
Out[98]:
   start_time  stop_time
0           1          5
1           7          9
2          20         22
3          22         26
4          27         30
5          35         40

In [99]: desired_events
Out[99]:
   start_time  stop_time
0           1          9
1          20         30
2          35         40
```

Explanation:

```
In [107]: events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift()
Out[107]:
0     NaN
1     2.0
2    11.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
5     5.0
dtype: float64

In [108]: (events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift() > allowable_gap)
Out[108]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool

In [109]: (events.start_time - events.stop_time.shift() > allowable_gap).cumsum()
Out[109]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Do you test it? I think is more 'elegant', but is slower. (~3.35 ms in my PC) The other one is longer, but faster (~900 µs).

Comment: You are right @Max . But, why? In your solution I think you iterated 3 times (groupby, max, and the conditional). Some ideas about this? (btw, I get the same solution, but was slower with few elements).

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras, "vectorized" (working with vectors/columns instead of working with scalars) approach is always faster, because most of numpy and pandas internal methods are written with Cython and perfectly optimized

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras, i've made a speed comparison for differently sized DFs: 6, 60, 600, 6000, 60000 - your solution was faster only for 6 rows - the more rows DF had the bigger was the difference in speed

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [DataFrame.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) function.
I made this assumption:

- start_time <= stop_time for all events

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
start_time = [  1,  7, 20, 22, 27, 35]
stop_time  = [  5,  9, 22, 26, 30, 40]
events = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': start_time, 'stop_time': stop_time})
allowable_gap = 2.0

desired_start_time = []
desired_stop_time  = []

start = None
end = None
for index, row in events.iterrows():
    if start == None and end == None:
        start = row['start_time']
        end = row['stop_time']
    else:
        if end + allowable_gap >= row['start_time']:
            end = row['stop_time']
        else:
            desired_start_time.append(start)
            desired_stop_time.append(end)
            start = row['start_time']
            end = row['stop_time']
desired_start_time.append(start)
desired_stop_time.append(end)

print(desired_start_time)
print(desired_stop_time)
```

#### Output:

> [1, 20, 35]
>  [9, 30, 40]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. My head was hurting when I tried to come up with code to manage previous event/current event, you did it exactly as I've wanted. Thanks a lot

This should be a real answer, since benchmarking is not done fairly. By doing as in accepted answer, you won't actually get start/end times of merged events, only how many of them are there.